My HP laptop doesn't detect RAM
The BIOS of my HP laptop (Victus 16) suddenly stopped detecting a RAM of two RAMs. I checked on CPU-Z, but both rams are detected.
I've tried:

Running Windows Memory Diagnostics tool. It says there is no problems at memory.
Re-installing Windows. No effect.
Updating BIOS. This made the situation worse. Before updating OS, sometimes BIOS detected two RAMs, but never now.
Replacing RAM. No effect, but a strange situation has occurred: before RAMs are PC4-25600, but I changed RAMs to the new RAMs made PC4-21300, but speed of memory still be detected of 3200MT/s in the Task Manager.

I've not tried:

Installing BIOS which got from outside of HP website. This is last resort.

How can I resolve this?

Definitely do not install BIOS update from third party! It can do no good, and possibly brick the machine beyond repair. BTW, look for hardware issue, e.g., a bent pin in RAM socket, or broken solder connection of socket to PCB.
